# if any value in column between two numbers print statement in python

Tags: python, pandas

Here is some data:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame( {'a': [1,2,3,4] })
df

    a
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
```

I try to do the statements below:

```
if df.loc[df['a'] > 1].any() | df.loc[df['a'] < 3].any():
    print("good")
else:
   print("bad")
```

to print good when any value in column a is bigger than 1 or less than 3 but it gives this error:

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

What is wrong with my code please?

Comment: What do you expect this to do?

Comment: @calgary - Each and every real number is greater than 1 or less than 3. So the Python code is `print("good")` unless `df` can be empty.

Comment: Hi this gives me error:

Comment: if df.loc[df['a'] > 1].any() | df.loc[df['a'] < 3].any():
    print("good")
else:
    print("bad")

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If compare scalars use `or` and also compare only mask, so [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) return scalar:

```
if (df['a'] > 1).any() or (df['a'] < 3).any():
    print("good")
else:
   print("bad")
```

> Notice [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60168428/if-any-value-in-column-between-two-numbers-print-statement-in-python/60168815#comment106420667_60168428):
>
> Each and every real number is greater than 1 **or** less than 3.

So maybe you want `and`:

```
if (df['a'] > 1).any() and (df['a'] < 3).any():
    print("good")
else:
   print("bad")
```

**Details**:

```
print(df['a'] > 1)
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
Name: a, dtype: bool

print((df['a'] > 1).any())
True

print (df['a'] < 3)
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: a, dtype: bool

print ((df['a'] < 3).any())
True
```

Solution should be simplify by [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html) with `inclusive=False` parameter, but it means more like `1` `AND` less like `3`:

```
if df['a'].between(1, 3, inclusive=False).any():
    print("good")
else:
   print("bad")


print (df['a'].between(1, 3, inclusive=False))
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
Name: a, dtype: bool

print (df['a'].between(1, 3, inclusive=False).any())
True
```

Comment: @calgary - Mea culpa, previous answer was wrong, so edited. Here is encessary compare only masks

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the following:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame( {'a': [1,2,3,4] })

def condition_method(a):
    return a > 1 or a < 3

df["condition"] = df.a.apply(condition_method)


if df["condition"].any():
    print("Good")
else:
    print("Bad")
```

But as already mention in the comment by [Armali](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60168428/if-any-value-in-column-between-two-numbers-print-statement-in-python#comment106420667_60168428) every real number is greater than 1 or less than 3. (Except you have an empty dataframe, in my solution this would be `Good`.)

Basically what this solution do is that whatever condition you put into the `condition_method` if any value fulfill the condition you win.

If you want to use loc you have to save the result from the condition in a table like this:

```
df.loc[df['a'] > 1, 'cond1'].any()
```

In the end it would look like this:

```
if df.loc[df['a'] > 1, 'cond1'].any() or df.loc[df['a'] < 3, 'cond2'].any():
   print("good")
else:
   print("bad")
```